# php api digest authentication multipart form data

Tags: iphone, base64

what is the best way for a php rest api server to receive images from a client (here iphone).

Currently, we are sending the base 64 encoded content of the image file to the api server from iphone as a POST variable. At server end, we decode this variable and then we are creating a new file based on the decoded content. this works fine.

What are the other ways we can receive images?

Answer (score 0):

For ease of receiving it in PHP, post it as a binary with multipart/form-data and access it via the $_FILES array. You could also do it as an [HTTP PUT](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

Comment: thanks Anomie... HTTP put may be a better option. I am not sure how can we send multipart/form-data via rest api post requests.

Comment: If you're sending your POST using NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection, it's just a matter of setting your Content-Type header and formatting the body correctly. If you're using some other library, you'd have to check the documentation for that library.